# Do memory addresses change and how can they be dynamically found?

Tags: c++, process, memory-address

I'm writing a simple program that accesses the memory of another process. I have been using a memory editor to find the addresses of the variables I want my program to retrieve and use with the ReadProcessMemory function. So far, there have been no problems, but I am unsure whether the addresses of the values may change depending on the environment the other program is being run on.

Aside from alterations to the program itself, should I be concerned about this? I have noticed that my memory editor saves the addresses relative to the location of the .exe (such as program.exe+198F6C), and I would love to implement my program like this, but I could not find any method for retrieving the current address of program.exe in C++.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they change.

The OS loads the process into different offsets each time it launches, and anything allocated with `new` or `malloc` is very likely to get different addresses each time the code is run.

Comment: Thank you. Will they stay constant relative to the address of the .exe?

Comment: Depends on the compiler, but in most cases, I would expect static variables to have a constant offset from the executable image. Stack- or heap-allocated ones are much more unpredictable

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here: location of variables inside a process's memory space, and the location of a process in physical memory. The first should concern you, the second should not.

Local variables (as well as global/static variables) will have the same address *relative* to the program location in memory. Dynamically allocated variables (new/malloc) will have different addresses each time.

When I say "memory", I mean the virtual memory space of a specific process: the address 0x100 in one process doesn't equal 0x100 in another process, and in general is different than cell number 0x100 in your RAM. 
The actual address isn't usually interesting, because both ReadProcessMemory and your memory editor only work with those relative addresses. You don't need the location of program.exe.

If you're interested in local variables, you can count on ReadProcessMemory returning a meaningful result each time. If you need memory which has been dynamically allocated, you need to find a local pointer, get the address of the allocated memory from it, and call ReadProcessMemory again.

Comment: static and global variables would be in the same address in the virtual memory address space, **but** local variables can be at different addresses because of “Address Space Layout Randomization” (ASLR). [please check this out](https://www.quora.com/In-C-why-does-the-memory-address-of-a-variable-change-every-time-I-run-the-program)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will change.  Write a program that outputs the memory address of a few variables and run it a few times.  Your output should differ each time, especially on other machines.

Comment: So far it has worked consistently on my desktop and laptop. I think this may have something to do with how the program I am accessing was written.

Answer (score 0):

You are also going to run into concurrency problems with multiple accesses of the same memory area.

Correct order - W1a, W1b,R1a,R1b,W2a,W2b,R2a,R2b
Incorrect order - W1a,W1b,R1a,W2a,W2b,R1b,R2a,R2b

To solve this problem you need to look at IPC, Inter Processor Communication:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication